# Pay Pal API - Take Payment on behalf of client that does not have Pay Pal account

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I have poured through the PayPal payment documentation and I think what I'm trying to do may not be possible but I hoped someone can show me that I'm wrong. I want to take a payment using Pay Pal's Standard payments form integrated into my web site but I need the payment to go to another person's (my client) bank account rather than my pay pal account. I see that you can direct the payment to a different pay pal account but I don't see an option to pay someone that does not have a pay pal account. I would prefer to not require my clients to set up a pay pal account.

Bottom Line: Do I have any options to take the payment using paypal API on my website then programmatically direct the payment to a bank account that is not tied to Pay Pal?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The longer answer is that there do exist solutions that will allow you to send money to a bank account, but they require approval and custom integration work and in general are way more trouble than they are worth--certainly more trouble than requiring recipients to open a PayPal account which can be done in minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Hopefully, something will change but for now, this seems like the answer.